# MySQL: How to reference to a result from count in nested select

Tags: mysql, select, max

I am learning MySQL with a sample database.
I have a table "production" where with columns: cd_code, company and year.
I would like to find which company has produced the most cds.

This:

```
select company, count(cd_code) from production group by company;
```

Which gives me the companies and how many CDs each has released.
Now from that table with columns (as appeared) company, count(code_cd)
I want to print the company which has the most CDs.
So I want the max of the 2nd column of the 2nd table.

What I am trying is this:

```
select max(res.cd_code) from (select company, count(cd_code) from production group by company) as res;
```

And I am getting error 1054:

> Unknown column 'cd_code' in 'field list'

What can I do?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are selecting `company, count(cd_code)` in `res` and hence there is no `cd_code` in res.

If you want to access the count of the `cd_code` from `res`, then try below:

```
          SELECT max(res.COUNT_CODE) 
          FROM
             (SELECT company, count(cd_code) AS COUNT_CODE 
              FROM production 
              GROUP BY company) as res;
```

Comment: I am getting this error: 'ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'cd_code' in 'field list'' :/

Comment: @Chris: You mentioned `SELECT company, count(cd_code) 
              FROM production 
              GROUP BY company` is working, right?? If yes, then are you sure of running the above query as I doubt it will have any issue?

Comment: Yers this is working: 'select company, count(code_cd) AS COUNT_CODE from production group by company;'.

Comment: @Chris: Then are you sure you running my query i.e. `SELECT max(res.COUNT_CODE)`?? **Please note, I am using  `COUNT_CODE` and not `cd_code`**.

Comment: I'm sorry Yogendra, I was typing incorrectly another field. It worked. Thank you very much. So, we used alias to refer to the new table..

Comment: @Chris We use `COUNT_CODE` alias to refer the derived column while `res` alias to refer the derived table.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this.

```
select max(cd_code) from (select company, count(cd_code) as cd_code from production  group by company);
```

Comment: I am getting this:
Every derived table must have its own alias